# Subset of training set produces good results while full training set produces poor results

Tags: svm, cross-validation, unbalanced-classes

I have an extremely unbalanced data set: around 200 positive samples and 70,000 negative samples. To overcome this problem I have tried to over-sample the minority class as suggested in previous questions here.

Since training the classifier (in my case I am using SVM) takes a long time on my computer I first trained a classifier on a small subset of my data picked randomly, the classifier gave solid results when tested on the test set, yet when I trained a classifier using the full training data the classifier produced very poor results. Does anyone have insight into why this is happening and what should i do? I have also tried using weights but it did not produce a different result.

Comment: How do you set the value of the SVM hyperparameter(s); e.g. $C$ or $\lambda$? When you say a **random** subset of the training data do you mean 200 positive samples + a small random subset of the negative data?

Answer (score 0):

You can try F1 score that is specifically designed for skewed classes. The idea is to measure both precision and recall, because usual error ratio doesn't work for skewed classes. E. g. in your case you could always predict "negative" and yet have 99.7% correct answers.

$$F_1 = 2\frac {precision * recall}{precision + recall}$$

More info on wiki: [F1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score)